# The following ArgumentError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#3752d): Invalid argument(s)

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]I am getting dirty state exception when redirecting on a new page after login. On this home page I am getting info from preferences.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Drawer drawer = new Drawer();

  String strName, strEmail, strImageURL;
  int userId;
  Image imgProfile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadSharedPref();
  }

  //Loading Shared value on start
  _loadSharedPref() async {
    print('In Shared Profile');
    try{
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      strName = prefs.getString('name');
      print('Shared Profile Name '+strName);
      setState(() {
        strName = prefs.getString('name');
        userId = prefs.getInt('userId');
        strEmail = prefs.getString('email');
        strImageURL = prefs.getString('avatar');
        imgProfile = Image.network(Config.PROFILE_PIC+strImageURL);
        print('Image URL ---- '+Config.PROFILE_PIC+strImageURL);
      });
    }catch(exception){
      print('SharedProfile '+exception);
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: whiteColor,
        drawer: sideDrawer(),
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Test Page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //Profile Details
  Widget profileDetail() {
    return new DrawerHeader(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new CircleAvatar(
              radius: 40,
              backgroundColor : blueColor,
              backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(Config.PROFILE_PIC+strImageURL),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  //Side Drawer
  Widget sideDrawer(){
    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Center(
            child: profileDetail(),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
            title: new Text('Requests'),
//          onTap: () => _onListTileTap(context),

          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
            title: new Text('Reviews'),
//            onTap: () => _onListTileTap(context),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
            title: new Text('Setting'),
//            onTap: () => _onListTileTap(context),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
            title: new Text('Tip'),
//            onTap: () => _onListTileTap(context),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
            title: new Text('Conditions'),
//            onTap: () => _onListTileTap(context),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
            title: new Text('About Us'),
//            onTap: () => _onListTileTap(context),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
            title: new Text('Log Out'),
//            onTap: () => _onListTileTap(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Cross-link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25428

Comment: can you add error screenshot?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari I have added screenshot. Please check

Comment: I thought issue is         imgProfile = Image.network(Config.PROFILE_PIC+strImageURL);
... What is code behind it pls elaborate more.

Comment: @iPatel So I found this issue was generating due to this one 
backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(Config.PROFILE_PIC+strImageURL)

Comment: Do you get this error only on hot-reload but also on full-reload or restart?

Comment: Please try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted to ensure your Flutter install is not corrupted.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer My issue is more related to the something else rather than installation. As I understand till now when I trying to get values from preferences it is creating issue.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here is what I found 
https://imgur.com/a/Frjh2R7

Comment: I'd check if you still can reproduce with `master` channel. And I'd still try to check the Flutter installation is clean (wiki link above)

Comment: Try `flutter clean` https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17740

Answer (score 5):

I went into the same kind of problem. Checking my variables having shared pref values for null or not worked for me.

Try checking strName, userId, strEmail, strImageURL, imgProfile are not null before using them in the widget.

```
if(strImageURL != null)
{
  print('filepaths: '+strImageURL);
}
```

Try this out

```
  //Profile Details
  Widget profileDetail() {
    return new DrawerHeader(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new CircleAvatar(
              radius: 40,
              backgroundColor : blueColor,
              backgroundImage: strImageURL ?? AssetImage('some static file path') : NetworkImage(Config.PROFILE_PIC+strImageURL),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't fill "name", "userId", "avatar" or "email" fields in your preferences and you are getting this error when trying to get with SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

just create statement everytime you trying to call the data from sharedPreference like this

```
body: yourDatainsharedPreference != null ?
       //do something
     :
      // do something
```